# How to make a canvas move with keyboard when I click on it on Python

Tags: python, canvas, tkinter

Im currently creating a chess game on python and I want to be able to move a pawn with my keyboard when I click on this pawn.

```
root = tk.Tk()

canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=1000, height=800)
canvas.pack()

img = tk.PhotoImage(file="pixil-frame-0.png")
image = canvas.create_image(100,0,image=img,anchor=tk.NW)

def move(event):

    if event.char == "a":
        canvas.move(image, -100, 0)
    if event.char == "d":
        canvas.move(image,100,0)
    if event.char == "w":
        canvas.move(image,0,-100)
    if event.char =="s":
         canvas.move(image,0,100)

root.bind("<Key>", move)

root.mainloop()
```

I expect to not be able to move the pawn if I dont click on it first but right now I can move it without having to click on it.

Comment: You need to select the piece, note where it currently is, grab it, move it, place it on another square, check if the move is legal, update its position if it is, or replace it where it was if it is not. Right now, you have a canvas item that follows the mouse cursor.

Comment: ***"when I click on this pawn"***: You have to use [`canvas.bind('<Button-1>', ...`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-events-and-bindings.htm)